# How do I update a param in Rails before it submits, based on a selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry if this is a super nooby question, but I have been trying to figure out this solution for a while.

Basically, I have a field in a form which requests a length of time. Currently it accepts numbers as months in a float, so if you want to put in 15 days, you would have to enter "0.5". I added a radio field which allows the user to select a type (months or days).

I tried adding

```
if params[:length_type] == "days"
  params[:length] = params[:length]/30
end
```

to the controller but I realized that even though the parameter was changing (as seen in debugger), it was being submitted first, which meant that if the user chose 15 days it would still be submitted as 15 months.

Next I tried adding this code to the model in a before_create where I was informed that:

> undefined local variable or method `params' for ...

I looked it up and apparently params are not accessible in the model, and more so if they were it would break MCV practice.

I am pretty confused as to where to go from here, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

(BTW I don't want to do this in JS because I am worried about the possibility of it being off on a users computer, unless there is a way around that?)

Comment: You should post more code. Specifically your controller. "even though the parameter was changing (as seen in debugger), it was being submitted first, which meant that if the user chose 15 days it would still be submitted as 15 months." that sounds like a problem with the order of commands in your controller.

Comment: you can add a method in controller which will handle this before going to the action. and you can simply add the method as `before_filter :methodname, only: [:update]` this will update the params as params are accesible in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the action (change params) in the **update** method in the controller before the **thing.update** method is called in it.  You do that if the record exists.  If it is a new record you will need to do the same thing in the controllers **create** method before **thing.save** is called.